# Override SaveOrUpdate Method in NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate

Can someone tell me how to override SaveOrUpdate Method in NHibernate?
I need to use the dll that will provide me a connection object and a function to execute database query. Now I need NHibernate to connect using that connection object and execute all the query through that function.
Please kindly let me know how to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you will need to register an event listener. This article : http://www.codinginstinct.com/2008/04/nhibernate-20-events-and-listeners.html provides an example on implementing the PerformSaveOrUpdate event handler.

The event object passed into PerformSaveOrUpdate has a Session property and the Session object has a Connection property.

Comment: Hi I checked that article. That's not suit my need. Can I let NHibernate to generate Insert/Update/Delete statment? I need to execute it on my own.